# AppCompat and Fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat

```
02-19 11:49:17.369: E/AndroidRuntime(4209): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.slidingmenus.fragments.HomeFragment
02-19 11:49:17.369: E/AndroidRuntime(4209):     at com.slidingmenus.MainActivity.displayCategoryView(MainActivity.java:242)
02-19 11:49:17.369: E/AndroidRuntime(4209):     at com.slidingmenus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:121)
```

Tried each and every steps suggested in stack overflow but they didn't help.

It works without an error in 4.0+ but in 2.3.x devices its giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in

```
line 242: fragment = new HomeFragment();
```

My imports from fragments are:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

and I'm using:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

Here is my home fragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;   

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {        
   public HomeFragment(){}

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main_fragment,container, false);

           return rootView;
    }
 }
```

Spent whole morning already trying to solve this. still no luck. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use `Fragment` from the support library.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

You also need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` and since you are using `AppCompat` your activity must extend `ActionbarActivity`.

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Update:

`ActionBarActivity` is deprecated use `AppCompatActivity` from support library. Don't forget to update your support repository to the latest.

Comment: And now you need to extend with `AppCompatActivity`. `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated.

Comment: Certainly you need to extend appcompact activity

Answer (score 2):

Try this code
Import:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

And  use

```
    Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.layout.layout_main_fragment, fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and resolved it by **import support library** and used

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Instead

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```